# Using colResizable plugin need to know which column header was resized

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I get the index of the column which was re-sized?  Resizing works but I can't find index or other header relevant information within e.currentTarget

```
var onResized = function (e) {

    console.log('E: ', e);

    // reference to the resized table
    var table = $(e.currentTarget);
    console.log('************** what is table?', table)
    var thisRow = table.find('thead tr');
    console.log('************** what is thisRow?', thisRow)
    var thisHere = thisRow.closest('th').index();
    console.log('************** what is here?', thisHere)
};

bindgrid.find('.grid-header-table').colResizable({
    liveDrag: true,
    onResize: onResized
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the description reported in [colResizable Events](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#events) you can get info about the grip (column separator used to resize) originating the resize event.

If the table contains 3 cols you can get values: 0 or 1. This means you can only know if you are acting/resizing the first two cols or the last two.

Such a value is:

```
$(e.target).parent().index()
```

In the following the snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#sample").colResizable({
    liveDrag: true,
    onResize: function (e) {
      var table = $(e.currentTarget); //reference to the resized table
      alert('Table grip index: ' + $(e.target).parent().index());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 55px;
}

.center {
  text-align: left;
}

#table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
}

th {
  border-top: 1px solid #2e638e;
  border-left: 1px solid #2e638e;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2e638e;
  border-right: 1px solid #2e638e;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: #012b4d 2px 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  text-indent: 5px;
  color: #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
}

td.left {
  border-left: 1px solid #2e638e;
}

td.right {
  border-right: 1px solid #2e638e;
}

td.bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2e638e;
}

label {
  color: #0361ae;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/js/colResizable-1.5.min.js"></script>


<div class="center">
    <br/><br/>
    <table id="sample" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td class="right">cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td class="right">cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left bottom">cell</td>
            <td class="bottom">cell</td>
            <td class="bottom right">cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That document calls out e.currentTarget, not sure how long it would have taken me to find it in e.target.